# Getting form widget name in Symfony2/Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

So, what I need to do is to output current element's ID in each `field_row`. What I came to is overriding Symfony's default field_row block with the following code:

```
{% block field_row %}
{% spaceless %}
<div class="clearfix" id="{{ form.get('name') }}-row">
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    <div class="input"&gt;
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_row %}
```

However, the `{{ form.get('name') }}` construct seems pretty awkward to me and I'm sure there's a more civilised way of doing this. Anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean the id generated by symfony? then it's just:

```
{{ id }}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! That's it, turned out to be pretty obvious, although I couldn't find it in the docs.